# Request.Form without Values

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

i have a problem
I have an A form with one with a hidden field that redirects to the other in a button.
In form B, i mus get the value of this hidden field by POST.

But when I do the Request.Form("Hidden_Field"), it only brings me the name of the field, when what I need is the VALUE.

any ideas?.

here is the code:

Form A:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="SIGNSYS_OUTPUT" runat="server" Value="123" />

Server.Transfer("~/VerifyAccountBGBAResult.aspx", True)
```

Form B:

```
Me.Value = Request.Form("SIGNSYS_OUTPUT")
```

This Request returns me in the value "SIGNSYS_OUTPUT".

Comment: it should work. Please show the HTML and also show exactly how you used Request.Form in your code.

Comment: Make sure your form gets submitted. If the page redirect it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Server.Transfer does not transfer the information unless the form got posted first, I'll assume this is the case.

Request.Form gets the information based on the name of the control, example.

```
<input type="hidden" name="SIGNSYS_OUTPUT" value = "123" />
```

When you use runat="server" the name is generated by .net. You'll need to do a viewsource to get the proper name. It might end up being something like this.

```
Request.Form("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$SIGNSYS_OUTPUT")
```

In your case, I think using Server.Transfer might not be the best solution. You could look at other solution like using a session, the database, process on the page and send to result to the other page, ect..

Comment: i cant found a name like this in de viewsource. Yes, but my boss want to do this with a server.transfer. With a session  variable is really easy

Comment: @Excedd if you can't find it in the viewsource, then you have an other problem. This mean the control isn't even there. It might be set to be hidden by some other code.